# Oracle 11g Catalog / System Tables DBA_COL_COMMENTS and DBA_OBJECTS Entries

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I am working on a project where the objective is simple. We have a surrogate key whose data type needs to change from integer to decimal(18,0) to accomodate more transactions due to business growth. Apparently, this field is very important and is referenced in thousands of objects.

I want figure out an automated way to identify all the objects where this field is present or referenced.Field name is say SRV_ACCS_XXX. That is tables/views/macros so on and so forth which has reference to this field.

Thought will use the catalog/system system tables :) .This is the problem I am facing. 
There are objects in dba_col_comments which has reference to field SRV_ACCS however these objects do not have entry into dba_objects - so I am ending up with object type as null.
The object names are like `"BIN$01gtIjJPB0vgRAALXeCowg==$0"` however they have a valid database schema name.

Is my approach right?
If so what are these types of objects - with names "BIN$01gtIjJPB0vgRAALXeCowg==$0"?
How can I eliminate temporary objects/volatile objects from result to get only permanently created objects?. Because everytime I run the query with out any modifications its producing different results.

Pls read the following query.

```
select 
current_date "Load_date",
NULL "Tower_owner",
'Oracle Production' as "Environment_Name",
Object_Details_Tbl.TABLE_NAME "Object_Name",
object_typ_tbl.object_type "Object Type",
1 "Num Occurances",
Object_Details_Tbl.Owner "Database Schema",
'p1etl1d8.edc.cingular.net' "Server",
'N/A' "Object_Repository",
'Oracle Table'  "Object_Description",
'N/A' "Object_Folder_Name", 
'N/A' "Object_Directory_Name",
'A' AS "Object_Status" 
from dba_col_comments Object_Details_Tbl
left outer join
dba_objects Object_Typ_Tbl
on
object_details_tbl.table_name = object_typ_tbl.object_name
and
object_details_tbl.owner = object_typ_tbl.owner
where Object_Details_Tbl.column_name like('%SRV_ACCS_%')
```

Thanks
Markiv.

Comment: I'm not sure the premise makes sense.  In Oracle, an `INTEGER` is a synonym for a `NUMBER(38,0)` while a `DECIMAL(18,0)` is a `NUMBER(18,0)`.  So you are trying to shrink the maximum value that can be stored in the column by 20 orders of magnitude.  That seems to contradict the stated desire to accommodate more transactions due to growth.  Do you really want to shrink the size of the column?

Comment: objects starting BIN$ will be those in the recylebin (`select * from user_recyclebin` to see).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your approach and the transaction rate. But for the `BIN$..` objects, they are deleted objects. No worries about them, just purge the recycle bin(it may take some time) and they should disappear.

Comment: Sorry for the initial confusion - the datatypes that I was mentioning in the original email was for teradata. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks a tonne for your feed back it really helps in understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Justing Cave for you inputs they were really helpful.